# How do I validate that each first letter in a name is in capital letters?

Tags: javascript, validation

I have one input where the user writes her/his first and last name. I need to validate if both first and second name start with capital letters. Also need to handle more than two names.

I've tried this in my validation object. I realize that I get a if for each element while mapping, not sure how to write this correctly.

```
 nameCheck(value){
        let name = value.split(" ");
        name?.map(element => {
        if(name?.length > 0 && element[0] === element[0].toUpperCase()){
            return true
        }
        else{
            return false

            }
         }
        )
    }
```

I'm calling it like this:

```
const isValidName = validate.nameCheck(form.creator)
   console.log(isValidName)
```

Here isValidName ends up undefined. All my other validation-checks are simple if-statements which works fine.

Any idea how to tackle this?

Answer (score 3):

You are not returning anything from the method `nameCheck`; But you are using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) here, and if you return the value that `map` returns, then it will return an array of Boolean values.

```js
const validate = {
  nameCheck(value) {
    let name = value.split(" ");
    return name?.map((element) => {   // change, Added return keyword
      if (name?.length > 0 && element[0] === element[0].toUpperCase()) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    });
  },
};

const isValidName = validate.nameCheck("Test user");
console.log(isValidName);
const isValidName2 = validate.nameCheck("Test User");
console.log(isValidName2);
```

I don't think that you want to `return an array`; you just want to `return a Boolean value` that tells whether the name is valid or not.

So you can use [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) here as:

```js
const validate = {
  nameCheck(value) {
    return value.split(" ").every((s) => s[0].toUpperCase() === s[0]);
  },
};

const isValidName = validate.nameCheck("Test user");
console.log(isValidName);
const isValidName2 = validate.nameCheck("Test User");
console.log(isValidName2);
```

---

**EDITED:** If there are multiple space between two word then you can filter out the empty string as

```js
const validate = {
  nameCheck(value) {
    return value
      .split(" ")
      .filter(Boolean)
      .every((s) => s[0].toUpperCase() === s[0]);
  },
};

const isValidName = validate.nameCheck("Test user");
console.log(isValidName);
const isValidName2 = validate.nameCheck("Test      User");
console.log(isValidName2);
```

---

Validation for `firstname` and `lastname`

**1)** **`Using split and regex`**

```
const names = value.split(/\s+/);
if(names.length > 1) /* There are multiple names */
```

**2)** **`Using split and Destructuring`**

```
const [firstname, lastname] = value.split(/\s+/);
if (firstname && lastname) {
  /* Both firstname and lastname is present  */
}
```

Comment: Good, except nameCheck will cause an exception for strings with two consecutive spaces (since the split will generate an empty string and s[0] will be out of bounds).

Comment: Great catch, Edited the code using `.filter(Boolean)`

Comment: Great, it works, but It dosent check if there are two names or more. Since both first and last name is required in my form I guess I need to check that whitespace is present in the string before doing anything else?

Comment: @Tore code edited, you can use either one of the two methods in the edited code. Have a look

Comment: I ended up doing this, wich kind of works: const checkWhiteSpace = new RegExp("\\s+");
            if(checkWhiteSpace.test(value)){
                return value
                .split(" ")
                .filter(Boolean)
                .every((s) => s[0].toUpperCase() === s[0]);}
                },

Comment: The only issue is that if I type in: "Tom LancelotPotter" the test still returns true because it only checks if its one whitespace in the string. I guess I also need to check if there is whitespace before each capital letter, except the first?